# Solving $2y'''(t)+3t\ y(t)=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a certain problem, I am trying to solve the ODE

$$2y'''(t)+3t\ y(t)=0$$

I am pretty clueless what to do here, any hint would be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try with power series method,maybe you will get idea in what format $y$ is

Comment: There is a solution which involves hypergeometric functions. So, following Half-Blood prince's suggestion is probably the way to go.

Comment: This is a Cauchy problem... can it be important?

Comment: Write $y$ as a general polynomial of $t$. Establish the formula for $y'''$. Write the differential equation. Identify the coefficient for a given degree of $t$. This gives a recurrence relation.